# Insert datagridview rows to SQL table

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am trying to save rows from datagridview to an SQL Server table using a stored procedure.

This is the C# code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server= localhost;Database = Vehiculum ;integrated Security = true");
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("inserproducts", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server= localhost;Database = Vehiculum ;integrated Security = true");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insertservisi", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        for (int i = 0; i < dtgservisimi.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kategoria", dtgservisimi.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@servisimi", dtgservisimi.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barkodi", dtgservisimi.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emertimi", dtgservisimi.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sasia", dtgservisimi.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@garancioni", dtgservisimi.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emri", txtemri.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mbiemri", txtmbiemri.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefoniI", txttelefoniI.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefoniII", txttelefoniII.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adresa", txtadresa.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@komuna", cmbkomuna.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodhuesi", cmbprodhuesi.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modeli", cmbmodeli.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@motorri", cmbmotori.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shasia", txtshasia.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tabela", txttabela.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@viti", txtviti.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shenime", txtshenime.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@punetori", lbluser.Text);

        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
```

And the stored procedure code:

USE [Vehiculum]
GO

```
         ALTER procedure [dbo].[insertservisi]
         @emri varchar(50) = null,
         @mbiemri varchar (50) =null,
         @telefoniI varchar (50) = null,
         @telefoniII varchar (50) = null,
         @adresa varchar (100) = null,
         @komuna varchar (50) = null,
         @prodhuesi varchar (50) = null,
         @modeli varchar (50) = null,
         @motorri varchar (50) = null,
         @shasia varchar (50) = null,
         @tabela varchar (50) = null,
         @viti varchar (50) = null,
         @kategoria varchar (100) = null,
         @servisimi varchar (20) = null,
         @barkodi int  = null,
         @emertimi varchar (max) = null,
         @sasia int = null,
         @garancioni varchar(200) = null,
         @shenime varchar(max) = null,

         @data datetime = null,
         @punetori varchar(100) = null


         as


        declare @id int;

        INSERT INTO 



        Servisimi_info
        (Emri,
        Mbiemri,
        TelefoniI,
        TelefoniII,
        Adresa,
        Komuna,
        Prodhuesi,
        Modeli,
        Motorri,
        Shasia,
        Tabela,
        Viti,
        Data_servisimit,
        Punetori)
         VALUES (@emri,
        @mbiemri,
        @telefoniI,
        @telefoniII,
        @adresa,
        @komuna,
        @prodhuesi,
        @modeli,
        @motorri,
        @shasia,
        @tabela,
        @viti,
        @data,
        @punetori)
     set @id = scope_identity();


         INSERT INTO Servisimi_produkti
        (Kategoria,
        Servisimi,
        Barkodi,
        Emertimi,
        Sasia,
        Garancion,
        Shenime,
        Id_servisimi)
         VALUES 

         (@kategoria,

        @servisimi,
        @barkodi,
        @emertimi,
        @sasia,
        @garancioni,
        @shenime,
        @id)
```

But I get this error

> Procedure or function has too many arguments specified
>    I am trying to store data data in two tables. The second table has a foreign key connected to primary key(first table). Also datagridview has multiple rows that has to be stored in second table with the same id(from table 1)
>   Where is the thing I missed or did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use using blocks to ensure your database objects are closed and disposed.

Don't use `.AddWithValue`. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Don't keep adding parameters at every iteration of the loop. Build the parameters collection once before the loop and assign the values that change in the loop.

You are executing your command after the loop. Only the last set of values will be entered.

```
    private void AddToDatabase()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server= localhost;Database = Vehiculum ;integrated Security = true"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("inserproducts", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@mbiemri", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtmbiemri.Text; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@telefoniI", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txttelefoniI.Text; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@telefoniII", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txttelefoniII.Text; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@adresa", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtadresa.Text; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@komuna", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = cmbkomuna.Text; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@prodhuesi", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = cmbprodhuesi.Text; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@modeli", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = cmbmodeli.Text; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@motorri", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = cmbmotori.Text; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@shasia", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtshasia.Text; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@tabela", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txttabela.Text; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@viti", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtviti.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@kategoria", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@servisimi", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@barkodi", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@emertimi", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = txtemri.Text; ;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sasia", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@garancioni", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@shenime", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = txtshenime.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@punetori", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = lbluser.Text;

            con.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i < dtgservisimi.Rows.Count -1; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@servisimi"].Value = dtgservisimi.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
                cmd.Parameters["@barkodi"].Value = (int)dtgservisimi.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
                cmd.Parameters["@emertimi"].Value = dtgservisimi.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;
                cmd.Parameters["@sasia"].Value = (int)dtgservisimi.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value;
                cmd.Parameters["@garancioni"].Value = dtgservisimi.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not very consistent.....

1. You have **7** parameters in your `INSERT INTO` list, but the `VALUES` collection only defines **6** values.....

   ```
   INSERT INTO products (Category, Model, Barcode, Name, Qty, Warranty, Shenime)
   VALUES (@category, @model, @barcode, @name, @qty, @warranty)
   ```
2. Your C# code defines and sets even **10** parameters - the last 3 are never used in your stored procedure (at least it doesn't seem that way, from the **fragment** you've posted):

   ```
   // never used in the stored procedure, it seems
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_fatura", txtid.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTime.Now);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@punetori", lbluser.Text);
   ```
3. You have a **typo** in your code - in the C# code, you have the **wrong** spelling for the `@waranty` parameter - only one "r":

   ```
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@waranty", warranty);
                                *********
   ```

   while in the stored procedure, you're using the **correct** spelling with **two** "r":

   ```
   VALUES (@category, @model, @barcode, @name, @qty, @warranty)
                                                     *********
   ```

You need to **pay more attention** to spelling and the number of parameters and values provided in your various party of the code. Try to make this all **consistent** and then see if it works

Answer (score 0):

In your procedure, you explicitly specified more columns than the values you passed.